# Where, when and how often to register/check for Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement GCM in my App. The App consists of a User Interface and a Service running in the background. The service is started by a boot broadcast receiver or when the App is started.

I followed the provided code example from google and so far it works. Google states, that you should check for play services in onCreate() and onResume() in your activity.

Should I also check for play services in my Service (in case the app is started, check for play services fails, user restarts device and my service is started via broadcast)?

Also do I really need to add the check in onCreate() since onResume() is called anyways when the App is started?

---Update---

Okay, I might made myself not clear enough. I'm only consuming GCM. The Receiver is of course a broadcast receiver which is made public in my manifest.

If a message comes in, I tell my service to do something. I asked if I should check for Play Services in my service so I can make sure the user will know that some things might not work if Play Services are not activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Should I also check for play services in my Service (in case the app is started, check for play services fails, user restarts device and my service is started via broadcast)?*

I haven't tried using a Boot `BroadcastReceiver` before, so I'm not familiar with it, which is why I'm not gonna comment a total answer.

---

*Also do I really need to add the check in onCreate() since onResume() is called anyways when the App is started?*

The reason as to why they are suggesting to do this can also be found in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-play):

> Apps that rely on the Play Services SDK should always check the device for a compatible Google Play services APK before accessing Google Play services features. It is recommended to do this in two places: in the main activity's `onCreate()` method, and in its `onResume()` method. The check in `onCreate()` ensures that the app can't be used without a successful check. The check in `onResume()` ensures that if the user returns to the running app through some other means, such as through the back button, the check is still performed.

---

**IF** you think that the checking of the Play Services is necessary before you start anything within your `Service`, then I think it's a good move.

Hope this helps somehow. Cheers!

PS: By the way, just in case you haven't checked it out yet, GCM now has a newer version called [firebase-cloud-messaging](/questions/tagged/firebase-cloud-messaging). Do check it out. :D

Site here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: I think I misinterpreted this passage of the documentation. Now that I think more about it, it means that if my app wouldn't work without Play Services, I should check in onCreate() and finish the activity if it fails. If, like in my case, it is nice to have Play Services but I don't rely on them, I'm fine by checking only in onResume()?

Comment: If you're sure that your app isn't completely dependent on the play services, I think it's fine. **BUT**, I'm not entirely sure if it's against best practice. Cheers!

Comment: I chose this answer as the best once since it helped me the most. After more thinking about my problem, I came to this conclusion: I will check for Play Service in onResume() AND in my BootBroadcastReceiver. The reason I do this (and not in onCreate()) is, that being able to receive one specific GCM message type doesn't make my App useless. Its still functionable and it never sends GCM. Therefore I use the checks as a friendly reminder that the user should activate the Play Services. I might even include a setting to fully deactivate GCM if somebody is concerned about their privacy

Answer (score 0):

In the case of FCM(previously GCM) you should check for Google Play services when you are about to use the Google Play services APIs. If your service can be started via a reboot broadcast, and your service uses FCM then you should check for play services there. So if your Activity is starting the service there would no need to check for Google Play services in the Activity. FCM should not negatively affect your app if Google Play services is missing but the device will not receive messages, or even get a registration token for that matter.